# Should I store the User Registration Agreement Checkbox in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and have a registration form that captures basic info such as email, username, and password. I will also have a Terms of use checkbox that will need to be checked in order to complete the registration.

My question is should I be storing this in the database? If so, should it be stored as a bit (1,0)?

Comment: why you think you need store it? A user should agree with the agreement when he registration,otherwise he cannot register. So when he register you already know he agrees and its always 1/true. So why you need to store it? But if you think user can register with or without agree you should save it at database how he registers.

Comment: I wanted to make sure for any legal reasons I have proof they agreed to the TOC, but I believe, like stated below, the act of registering and making the TOC checkbox required is proof they agreed during registration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you would not store this checkbox value unless you would allow the user to register without checking this box (which i assume you would not). If you want to store the value into database it would be boolean data type that is 0 or 1. Hope that helps

Comment: don't you mean int instead boolean

Comment: If you using mysql and PHPAdmin interface it would be TINYINT.

Comment: Thanks! If I don't store it and someone wanted proof that they agreed to it, is the registration proof enough that they agreed to the terms & conditions?

Comment: I believe if you mention these things in the term and condition it will give more sense.  You can say by registration to this website you will automatically comply to our term and conditions. Also you can email T&C them on registration and attach one of your email as BBC so you had a proof if you require. Mark question as correct if it does helps you. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Unless the policy will never change, you should track the timestamp of agreement or version of the policy agreed to at the time the user clicks the button.  Then when you update the policy you increment the version (or store the policy itself in the DB and use a created/updated timestamp).  When the user logs into the system again you check the time/version agreed to and the current time/version of the policy and determine if the user has agreed to the latest version.

If you don't do it this way and you ever change the policy, you will have to force every user to agree to it every time they log on to ensure they have agreed to the right version.  Otherwise they can use the argument, "That's not what it said when I agreed to it."